# Error en la pantalla de inicio

Tags: android-studio, layout

Ayer descargué Android Studio, todo iba bien hasta que de repente la pantalla en el diseño se puso gris con este texto. No llevo nada de código, no he modificado nada y no tengo idea de como solucionarlo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado el Android SDK? ¿Tienes instalada la versión 29 del SDK?

Comment: Si, ayer trabajaba bien, hasta se logró ver en mi celular bien. Pero al crear otro Proyecto salió así.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el xml de la Activity?

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe ser por las librerías (Tu proyecto no sabe como utilizar el ConstraintLayout de AndroidX) y ese xml esta utilizando androidx (Puedes investigar que es androidx). Intenta apretando "Refactor>>Migrate to AndroidX..." eso debería solucionar ese problema y no afecta el código que estés hacinado, igualmente te pregunta si quieres guardar una copia por cualquier error que pueda suceder, lo que es opcional.